# how to make my keyboard enter/go button work

Tags: angular, keyboard, ionic2

Please take a look at my image [image] .

after entering the data inside my input field and clicking on the keyboard enter/Go button, it is not doing anything it is acting like ideal.

> is there any plugin to control the keyboard(enter,search,go..etc) buttons to act like (click) function.
>   How to activate the enter/go button in every input fields?.

**Update**

here is my html code

```
  <ion-item>
      <ion-label primary floating>Email/Mobile</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="loginId" pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}$" required></ion-input>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item>
      <ion-label primary floating>Password</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="password" [(ngModel)]="passwd" required></ion-input>
    </ion-item>

    <p>{{loginMsg}}</p>


  <div padding>
  </div>

  <button ion-button full color="light" (click)="submit();" >LOGIN</button> <br>

  <div class="text" (click)="forgotPasswd()">

  <p > Forgot your password ?</p>
  </div>

  <div padding>
  </div>

  <div class="text-padding-bottom" (click)="registration();">
    <p > No account yet ? <b>Create One</b></p>
  </div>
```

if you see one of my page has input type="search" i am able to get search button in the key board but that button is also showing ideal
here is the code for it.

```
<ion-row>
        <ion-col width-80>
            <ion-item>
                <ion-input type="search" placeholder="search products"[(ngModel)]="searchValue"></ion-input>
            </ion-item>
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col width-20>
            <button ion-button icon-only (click)="searchText();"> 
              <ion-icon name="search"></ion-icon>
            </button>
        </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
```

Comment: Is there a button in the form or just input fields?

Comment: two input field like login button I have three click function in the login page

Comment: I have the input filed in many place of my project how can i control the keyborad botton what is should do when ever i click

Comment: did you use `<input type=submit>` in your form?

Comment: You need to add `type="submit"` in the **button**

Comment: @sebaferreras for this page it is ok but for type="search" it is not working and when my courser is in first text box and when i click enter it is not going to second text box

Comment: @Michael i tried this one it is not working in my case

Comment: Can you post the actual code? I can't see images hosted on SO where I am.

Comment: @silentsod please check my updated question

Comment: @sebaferreras, i tried using button type="submit". but still the form is not submitted on keyboard button. Any other option?

Comment: @AishApp same here also nothing works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the output. Copy your html code inside form and use `(submit)` to submit the form. Also as suggested in the comments, we have to use type="submit" for the button which should get executed on keyboard go button.

```
<form (submit)="submit()">
<ion-item>
      <ion-label primary floating>Email/Mobile</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="loginId" pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}$" required></ion-input>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item>
      <ion-label primary floating>Password</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="password" [(ngModel)]="passwd" required></ion-input>
    </ion-item>

    <p>{{loginMsg}}</p>


  <div padding>
  </div>

  <button ion-button full color="light" type="submit">LOGIN</button> <br>

  <div class="text" (click)="forgotPasswd()">

  <p > Forgot your password ?</p>
  </div>

  <div padding>
  </div>

  <div class="text-padding-bottom" (click)="registration();">
    <p > No account yet ? <b>Create One</b></p>
  </div>
</form>
```

Try this out.

Comment: What about search should they also have move to form to activate the search go button

Comment: how to close android keyboard after click "go" button on keyboard?

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it with the event **KeyPress**

```
<ion-input clear-input (keypress)="eventHandler($event.keyCode)"></ion-input>
```

And execute the function when the user presses the enter key on the device

```
eventHandler(keyCode) {
  console.log('keyCode: ', keyCode);
  if (keyCode == 13) {
   /* code */
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try using `(keyup.Enter)="confirmForm()"` in the last `ion-input` of the form where `confirmForm()` is the method you call when clicking the button that submits the form; for this solution you don't need `type="submit"` nor `(submit)="fn()"` on the `<form>` element